# AngularJS - Incorrect order in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have chaps defined in my controller like this:

```
  $scope.chaps =  [{"id":"1","chap_no":"1","name":"chap 1"},
                  {"id":"2","chap_no":"2","name":"chap 2"},
                  ...
                  {"id":"14","chap_no":"14","name":"chap 14"},
                  {"id":"15","chap_no":"15","name":"chap 15"}];
```

and in the view, I have:

```
<li ng-repeat="ch in chaps | orderBy:'chap_no'">{{ch.name}}</li>
```

but I'm getting the wrong order (10 after 1, 20 after 2, and so on)

```
chap 1, chap 10, chap 11, chap 12, chap 13, chap 14, chap 15, chap 2, chap 3, ...
```

Here's the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Pc84ooB6dp2zoHXeawYn?p=preview

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `chap_no` property is a string so its ordered as a string.

You can create a custom `filter` like:

```
app.filter('customSort',function(){
    function sort (a, b) {
        if (a > b) { return 1; }
        if (a < b) { return -1; }

        return 0;
    }

    return function(arrInput, prop) {
        var arr = arrInput.sort(function(a, b) {
            return sort(+a[prop], +b[prop]);
        });
        return arr;
    }
})
```

So then in your html you can use the filter like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="ch in chaps | customSort:'chap_no'" >{{ch.name}}</li>
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/UWvinthK9r0zgRbHMCGd?p=preview

Comment: Is this still valid? doesn't seem to work for me and I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: make sure you use single quotation marks around the property. Eg. `orderBy:'chap_no'` instead of `orderBy:chap_no`

Comment: The sentiment of this answer is correct, but the code is not.  As @Voles says, make sure you use quotes around your property, and also, `:number` doesn't do anything in angular; the plnkr only 'works' because it's doing NO sorting due to having no quotes, and the list is already sorted!