# Sorting table rows using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm just getting started with AngularJS and I'm trying to sort my table so that when a tableheader is clicked the rows are sorted per that table header.

Here is my plnkr link:
http://plnkr.co/edit/mbTq5865KKNzlvpJJy1l

Here is my relevant code:
Controller code:

```
$scope.setRepoSortOrder = function(order) {
      if ($scope.repoSortOrder === order) {
        if ($scope.repoSortOrder.charAt(0) === '+') {
          order = order.replace('+', '-');
        } else {
          order = order.replace('-', '+');
        }
      }
      $scope.repoSortOrder = order;
    };
```

Table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><a href="" ng-click="setRepoSortOrder('-name')">Name</a></th>
            <th><a href="" ng-click="setRepoSortOrder('+stargazers_count')">Stars</a></th>
            <th><a href="" ng-click="setRepoSortOrder('-language')">Language</a></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="repo in repos | orderBy:repoSortOrder">
            <td>{{repo.name}}</td>
            <td>{{repo.stargazers_count | number}}</td>
            <td>{{repo.language}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So when the name th is clicked the rows should be sorted by the names - same with stargazers_count and language. If a th is clicked again it should be sorted in the opposite order (if I click name first it's sorted by names in asc order - if I click it again it's sorted in desc order).

Finally: name and language should initially sort in asc order while stargazers_count should sort in desc order initially.

I've done this myself but I don't know if I'm doing it the best way possible. Since I'm not used to the "angular style" I would like to hear how people familiar with AngularJS would handle this. Please check out the plnkr link to see if you could improve it.

Any replies are appreciated!

Comment: You might try a custom filter as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842630/angularjs-incorrect-order-in-ng-repeat)

Comment: @Pheonixblade9
I've looked at the question but I don't quite see how a filter would help me. Anyways I've come up with my own solution (see the plnkr link) but I don't know if it's the best way coding-wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that can improve is to use a reverse flag of the [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) filter like this:

```
$scope.repoSortOrder = "-stargazers_count";
$scope.isReverse = false;

$scope.setRepoSortOrder = function(order) {
  $scope.isReverse = ($scope.repoSortOrder === order) ? !$scope.isReverse : false;
  $scope.repoSortOrder = order;
};
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/CM1BGkQc0AYbrraAPq8r?p=preview