# How can I order integers numerically in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I am displaying a list ordered by `id` with the following code:

```
            <dl class="dl-horizontal" ng-repeat="projectManager in projectManagers| orderBy: 'id'">
                <dt>{{projectManager.id}}</dt>
                <dd>{{projectManager.givenname}} {{projectManager.surname}}</dd>
            </dl>
```

But the ideas are being ordered alphabetically:

```
1
11
13
21
25
3
35
```

**How can I order them numerically?**

Comment: Can you post your controller code? And assuming your getting this data remotely also the JSON of the data? I presume it is coming in as a string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842630/angularjs-incorrect-order-in-ng-repeat/16842872#16842872

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code. The id's in your JSON array must be strings, you should remove the quotation marks and this will work just fine

Comment: Exactly, `orderBy: id` works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass custom function to `orderBy`:

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal" ng-repeat="projectManager in projectManagers| orderBy: parseLikeAPro">
```

and in controller:

```
 $scope.parseLikeAPro = function(pm) {
    return pm.id | 0;
  }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/xZx9dNFvryLptgPv6SiZ?p=preview

[docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)